# Iterate through an object and count all strings containing specific text within each and all arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have an object containing arrays, I want to count the number of occurrences a particular string is found across all arrays in the object.

```
const festivals = {
  'Danny': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Jimbo': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Richard': ['Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'John': ['Glastonbury','Leeds']
}

 let totalFestivals = 0
 let target = 'Benicassim'

for (let festival in festivals){
  if (festivals[festival] === target){
    totalFestivals++
  }
}
console.log (totalFestivals). //
```

Comment: `if (festivals[festival].includes(target))`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach needs another loop for looping though the arrays before you can compare the elements. You're comparing an entire array with the `target`

```js
const festivals = {
  'Danny': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Jimbo': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Richard': ['Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'John': ['Glastonbury','Leeds']
};

let totalFestivals = 0;
let target = 'Benicassim';

for (let festival in festivals) {
  for(let fest of festivals[festival]) {
    if(fest === target) {
      totalFestivals++
    }
  }
}

console.log(totalFestivals)
```

**Alternatively ....**

You can use array methods as follows to count `target` occurrences:

```js
const festivals = {
  'Danny': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Jimbo': ['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'Richard': ['Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'],
  'John': ['Glastonbury','Leeds']
};

const target = 'Benicassim';

const totalFestivals = Object.entries(festivals).reduce(
    (total, [name, fests]) => 
    total + fests.filter(fest => fest === target).length, 0
);

console.log( totalFestivals );
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like that?...

```js
for (let festival in festivals) {
  const festivalArray = festivals[festival];
  for (let i = 0; i < festivalArray.length; i++) {
    if (festivalArray[i] === target) {
      totalFestivals++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First, the == is not working because you are telling javascript this:

**Example with Danny:**

```
    if(['Glastonbury','Glastonbury','Leeds','Leeds','Leeds','Benicassim','MadCool'] == 'Benicassim'){
        ...
    }
```

**Instead you do this:**

```
festivals[festival].includes(target)
```

**Details:**

The includes function return true if the parameter is inside a list.

**Problem:**

But because of the way you write the function, your result will be max 4, because you have 4 list and your function and the includes do not count the occurrences.

**Solution:**

With the second for in the code below you will compare every index of the current list(example : 'Danny' list) with target and if they are equal the totalFestivals increase.

```
for (let festival in festivals){
    for(var i = 0; i < festivals[festival].length; i++){
        if (festivals[festival][i] === target){
            totalFestivals++
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const festivals = {
  Danny: [
    "Glastonbury",
    "Glastonbury",
    "Leeds",
    "Leeds",
    "Leeds",
    "Benicassim",
    "MadCool"
  ],
  Jimbo: [
    "Glastonbury",
    "Glastonbury",
    "Leeds",
    "Leeds",
    "Leeds",
    "Leeds",
    "Benicassim",
    "MadCool"
  ],
  Richard: ["Glastonbury", "Leeds", "Leeds", "Benicassim", "MadCool"],
  John: ["Glastonbury", "Leeds"]
};
const target = "Glastonbury";
let totalFestivals = 0;
const ar = [];
for (var festival in festivals) {
  festivals[festival].forEach((festivalProperty) => {
    totalFestivals += festivalProperty === target ? 1 : 0;
  });
}
console.log(totalFestivals);
```